# Can we tell chef-client to run particular resources?

Tags: chef-infra

I have written a chef recipe, which will create 2 users. I want to tell chef-client to create one or two user based on tags (This is feasible in Ansible) I want to implement same in chef.

Recipe: *users*

```rb
user 'user1' do
  comment 'A random user1'
  uid '1234'
  gid '1234'
  home '/home/random'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  password '$1$JJsvHslasdfjVEroftprNn4JHtDi'
end
user 'user2' do
  comment 'A random user2'
  uid '1234'
  gid '1234'
  home '/home/random'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  password '$1$JJsvHslasdfjVEroftprNn4JHtDi'
end
```

In my *users* recipe, I have two resources `user1` and `user2`.
I have launched an EC2, I want to run the *users* recipe, but I do not want both users be created on EC2.

Similarly, In my organisation we have 200 employees we dont want all users to be created on newly launched EC2. Please guide how to manage user creation, on Chef standards.

Comment: Yes you can. Please be more precise regarding what you tried already.

Comment: If you want to control the users on your environment consider using the community "users" cookbook. It uses a databag to control user settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific feature like in Ansible or Salt for this. You can use an override run list to specify a run list that will only be used that one time, though not all cookbooks behave well under it. If you want to write your Ruby code to allow this, you totally can.

```
unless tag?('thingy')
  user 'one'
  user 'two'
end
user 'three'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, it sounds to me like you need to look into the `users_manage` resource from the [users](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/users) cookbook, that creates all users in a specific group. 
You can then set a different group name per environment, and control which users are in that group e.g. by using different data_bags.